# RegEx with Pipes and IPs not working

Tags: regex

The RegEx:

`^([0-9\.]+)\Q|\E([^\Q|\E])\Q|\E`

does not match the string:

`1203730263.912|12.66.18.0|`

Why?

Comment: you have to espace the pipe. What regex engine are you using?

Comment: another community? Sure! go ahead. I'm pretty sure you'll return back...

Comment: \Q \E should be escaping enough for any scenario in my book. Regarding the recent hate-attacks on my questions. Either they are racist or something else, but I am receiving a torrent of downvotes to eligble questions, since I change my display name.

Comment: No. I think its an unique question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**From PHP docs**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php),

`\Q` and `\E` can be used to ignore regexp metacharacters in the pattern.

[**For example:**](http://regex101.com/r/fU3fH9/13)

`\w+\Q.$.\E$` will match one or more word characters, followed by literals `.$.` and anchored at the end of the string.

And your regex should be,

```
^([0-9\.]+)\Q|\E([^\Q|\E]*)\Q|\E
```

OR

```
^([0-9\.]+)\Q|\E([^\Q|\E]+)\Q|\E
```

You forget to add  `+` after `[^\Q|\E]`. Without `+`, it matches single character.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sB6pV0/5)

**Explanation:**

- `^` Starting point.
- `([0-9\.]+)` Captures digits or dot one or more times.
- `\Q|\E` In PCRE, `\Q` and `\E` are referred to as Begin sequence. Which treats any character literally when it's included in that block. So `|` symbol in that block tells the regex engine to match a literal `|`.
- `([^\Q|\E]+)` Captures any character not of `|` one or more times.
- `\Q|\E` Matches a literal pipe symbol.

Comment: Giving you the answer for great information, althouh it does not work in Python on your Demo page, strangly this does: ^([0-9\.]+)\|([0-9\.]+)\|

Comment: PCRE supports this feature I donno whether python supports this or not.

Comment: Good explanation for `\Q\E`, but in this case it's compatible with  `^([0-9.]+)\|([^|]+)\|` and simpler. Demo: http://regex101.com/r/sB6pV0/6 Note: characters inside character classes don't need escaping (with a few minor exceptions), you can just escape `|` in this case like: `\|`

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer seems somewhat incorrect so I wanted to address this for future readers.

If you did not already know, using `\Q` and `\E` ensures that any character between `\Q` ... `\E` will be matched literally, not interpreted as a metacharacter by the regular expression engine.

First and most important, `\Q` and `\E` is **NOT** usable within a bracketed character class `[]`.

```
[^\Q|\E]  # Incorrect
[^|]      # Correct
```

Secondly, you do not follow that class with a quantifier. Using this, the correct syntax would be:

```
^([0-9.]+)\Q|\E([^|]+)\Q|\E
```

Although, it is much simpler to write this out as:

```
^([0-9.]+)\|([^|]+)\|
```